# What is "YOUR_APP_PACKAGE_NAME" for Android in React Native Auth0?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, auth0

I'm following [these instructions](https://github.com/auth0/react-native-auth0) on how to add Auth0 to my React Native app, and in the section about Android callbacks it refers to a property called "YOUR_APP_PACKAGE_NAME". Does anyone know what that is or where to find it?

Answer (score 0):

I found this by googleing:

> The package name is a unique name to identify a specific app. Generally, the package name of an app is in the format domain.company.application, but it’s completely up to the app’s developer to choose the name. The domain portion is the domain extension, like com or org, used by the developer of the app.

http://www.aftvnews.com/how-to-determine-the-package-name-of-an-android-app/#targetText=The%20package%20name%20is%20a,the%20developer%20of%20the%20app.

Answer (score 0):

The package name is available in the app/build.gradle file as the applicationId value.